# Why does Google Tag manager append at the end of the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager

I am currently trying to implement the Google Tag Manager but I run into a problem since the GTM appends the tags right before the closing tag of the body.

Whenever I have a template that needs to call a bit of code from one of the scripts in the Google Tag Manager I get an undefined error. This is obvious since it does not matter where I place my script in my view, GTM will always come after it since it appends right before the closing body tag.

Is there any way to fix this behaviour and why does Google do it like this? I understand that it helps with non-blocking but they might as well just place async attributes on the scripts and it will almost do the same?

An example I have Facebook Pixel as one of my tags in GTM and I need to be able to make a specific event call when I am loading a certain page as my view.

```
fbq('track', 'Search');
```

Ofcourse this needs a fbq instance to begin with. This leave me with only one option and that is to try and place my script in my footer which is a general template and it will get messy.

Any workaround for this behaviour?

Comment: remove async attr or reconsider the way you are using

Comment: We can only guess when it comes to Googles intentions. I suggest you rephrase your question to address your actual problem ("how do I access variables in GTM from a script loaded in the page head") which is probably more answerable than "why was the software designed that way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that the Facebook library is not completely loaded when you are calling your function.
One method would be to migrate your Facebook code to GTM trigger it on all pages
and fire your specific code on dom ready

You could also use the code from below and see when the _fbq.loaded variable is set to true.
https://gist.github.com/chrisjhoughton/1dc91dd7bd95717e08d3

You would have to create trigger based on this javascript variable.
Hope this helps